# Google docs importXML issue

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xml-import

I'm trying to import info on Tesco Directs website into a Google Docs spreadsheet, however everything I try fails with the error message "The xPath query given could not be evaluated."

My code looks like:

```
=importXml("http://www.tesco.com/direct/keter-e-composter/210-5529.prd";"//li[@class='current-price']")
```

Similar importXML commands work with every other website without issues. Any suggestions why Tesco's would be different?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You used a ; instead of ,

   `=importXml("http://www.tesco.com/direct/keter-e-composter/210-5529.prd","//li[@class='current-price']")`
2. Your result from above will get split into three cells, so I would go deeper with the xPath to get the //span[@class='pounds'], by that you should get 35 without the pound sign and 0 at the end.
   Therefore the whole function would be,

   `=importXml("http://www.tesco.com/direct/keter-e-composter/210-5529.prd","//li[@class='current-price']//span[@class='pounds']")`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work for me. Still getting the error: error: "The xPath query given could not be evaluated."

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a wildcard instead of LI infront of your xpath - also the url you shared above when going to the site - there is no price listed for the specific item so that class doesn't exist - however here is another product from the same site - with the example variation on the xpath:

```
=importXml("http://www.tesco.com/direct/dyson-dc40-multi-floor-upright-vacuum-cleaner/774-5238.prd","//*[@class='current-price']")
```